# Error when running unit test from console using Visual Studio 17.1

Tags: msbuild, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, coverlet

Getting the error below when running the unit test from the command line. This runs fine on Windows 10 machine and is failing in Windows 7.

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover --logger "trx;LogFileName=unit_tests.xml" --configuration Release
```

```
Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.StackCrawlMarkHandle, Boolean, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean, System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.Reflection.AssemblyName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.ExtensionFramework.TestPluginCache.CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve(System.Object, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.Interfaces.AssemblyResolveEventArgs)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformAssemblyResolver.AssemblyResolverEvent(System.Object, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.GetFirstResolvedAssemblyFromResolvingEvent(System.Reflection.AssemblyName)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingEvent(System.Reflection.AssemblyName)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingResolvingEvent(IntPtr, System.Reflection.AssemblyName)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.ExtensionFramework.TestPluginDiscoverer.GetTestExtensionsFromAssembly[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.ExtensionFramework.TestPluginDiscoverer.GetTestExtensionsFromFiles[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.String[], System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.ExtensionFramework.TestPluginDiscoverer.GetTestExtensionsInformation[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.ExtensionFramework.TestPluginCache.GetTestExtensions[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.ExtensionFramework.TestPluginCache.DiscoverTestExtensions[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.String)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.Hosting.TestRuntimeExtensionManager.Create(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Logging.IMessageLogger)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.Hosting.TestRuntimeProviderManager.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.TestEngine..ctor()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestPlatform..ctor()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.TestPlatformFactory.GetTestPlatform()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.TestPlatformHelpers.TestRequestManager..ctor()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.TestPlatformHelpers.TestRequestManager.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Processors.RunTestsArgumentProcessor+<>c.<get_Executor>b__6_0()
   at System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ViaFactory(System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode)
   at System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ExecutionAndPublication(System.LazyHelper, Boolean)
   at System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].get_Value()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Processors.ArgumentProcessorFactory+<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<WrapLazyProcessorToInitializeOnInstantiation>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].get_Value()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Executor.GetArgumentProcessors(System.String[], System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Processors.IArgumentProcessor> ByRef)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Executor.Execute(System.String[])
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Program.Main(System.String[])
C:\Users\loadbuilder\.nuget\packages\coverlet.msbuild\3.1.2\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets(71,5): error MSB4044: The "Coverlet.MSbuild.Tasks.CoverageResultTask" task was not given a value for the required parameter "InstrumenterState".
```

Comment: Getting this too and this is the only Google result >_<

Comment: I have the same problem with Win Server 2008 R2. .NET 6 is not supported on Win 7 nor Win server 2008 R2: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/supported-os.md

Comment: Windows 7 SP1 is supported with Extended Security Updates installed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be related to using Windows 7.
The bug is tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/24124

As a workaround, you can [install an older version of .NET 6.0 which is called "**SDK 6.0.103**" under 6.0.3 in the download section at Microsoft](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0). You then place a file `global.json` in the root of your project, containing:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.103"
  }
}
```

Now your `dotnet` commands will use that version. It should work with that one. Hopefully there will be a fix.

NET 6.0 and Windows 7 so far worked fine together, even though it seems it's not *officially supported* anymore.